# Agrupar dos tablas MySQL

Tags: sql

Hola lo que quiero hacer es agrupar dos columnas de dos tablas que seria
en la

tabla

> usersoperacion

la columna

> nombre

junto con la 
tabla

> orders

y la columna

> productName

```
SELECT usersoperacion.nombre, orders.productName
FROM usersoperacion op inner join orders prod on op.nombre
```

intento esto pero me dice que no existe pero si existe, alguien sabe por que y como hacerlo ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos problemas.

El primero es que usas un alias para las tablas, por tanto, debes usarlo siempre que te vayas a referir a las columnas de esa tabla. Cuando usas alias, las tablas no se conocerán (en esa consulta) por sus nombres reales, sino por ese alias.

El segundo es que el `JOIN` no está completo.

Si lo pones así, debería funcionar:

```
SELECT 
    op.nombre, 
    prod.productName
FROM usersoperacion op      -- aquí dijiste que la tabla tendrá el alias op
    INNER JOIN orders prod -- y que esta tabla se llamará prod
    ON op.nombre=prod.productName
```